# Cannot move out of an 'Rc'

Tags: enums, rust, traits

Deriving PartialEq on an enum with a unit variant of an Rc trait object seems to trigger a `Cannot move out of an 'Rc'` error.

I've been able to create a small code sample that reproduces the error. Is there a way to fix the error without manually implementing PartialEq for the enum? This happens in 5 places in a codebase.

Code Example:

```
use failure::Error;
use serde_derive::{Deserialize,Serialize};
use std::rc::Rc;

trait MyTrait {
}

impl PartialEq for MyTrait {
    fn eq(&self, rhs: &Self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

impl MyTrait for String {
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B(Rc<dyn MyTrait>),
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    println!("{}",MyEnum::A == MyEnum::B(Rc::new(String::from("whee"))));
    Ok(())
}
```

Here's the generated PartialEq:

```
#[inline]
fn eq(&self, other: &MyEnum) -> bool {
    {
        let __self_vi =
            unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::discriminant_value(&*self) } as
                isize;
        let __arg_1_vi =
            unsafe { ::std::intrinsics::discriminant_value(&*other) } as
                isize;
        if true && __self_vi == __arg_1_vi {
            match (&*self, &*other) {
                (&MyEnum::B(ref __self_0), &MyEnum::B(ref __arg_1_0)) =>
                (*__self_0) == (*__arg_1_0),
                _ => true,
            }
        } else { false }
    }
}
```

And here's a link to the issue:
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31740

So this might just be a language bug right now. Manually implementing PartialEq for all the enums this is an issue for isn't feasible right now, so I'd be curious if there's a workaround.

Comment: As a workaround it seems to be possible to box the trait object like `Rc<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad16dbd281f722e4a2acf1959e275884))